# not able to run supervisorctl command as a different user in docker

Tags: bash, docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have dockerfile with following content

```
FROM 2.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/pa-amazonlinux:latest
# FROM amazonlinux:2

# install core packages
RUN yum update -y && \
    amazon-linux-extras install -y python3.8 postgresql14 nginx1 epel && \
    yum install -y gcc git openldap-devel openssl-devel crontabs python38-devel mariadb-devel supervisor which tar python2-requests

# install extra packages
RUN yum install -y libpq-devel libaio

ENV PATH "$PATH:~/.local/bin"
#RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash gitlab-runner
#RUN usermod -aG wheel gitlab-runner

WORKDIR /app/pa
# copy over our source code
COPY . /app/pa/

# copy over configuration
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/


# create directories used by the app
RUN mkdir /var/log/pa && \
    mkdir /var/www && \
    mkdir /var/www/pa
RUN mkdir /virtualenvs

RUN chown -R gitlab-runner:gitlab-runner /var/log/pa
RUN chown -R gitlab-runner:gitlab-runner /var/www
RUN chown -R gitlab-runner:gitlab-runner /var/www/pa
RUN chown -R gitlab-runner:gitlab-runner /virtualenvs

# setup virtual environment for the app
RUN python3.8 -m venv /virtualenvs/pa && \
    source /virtualenvs/pa/bin/activate && \
    pip install -r requirements/base.txt

RUN ldconfig

RUN chmod u+x docker_entrypoint.sh

RUN echo "NETWORKING=yes" > /etc/sysconfig/network
```

i am creating my ecs task with docker_entrypoint.sh content being

```
NAME="maestro_ecs"
echo "$ENVIRONMENT"
DJANGODIR=/app/platform_analytics
service=ecs
echo "Starting $NAME as `whoami`"
tag_filter="ma-ecs-"$ENVIRONMENT

# Get the list of runners with the specified tag
page=1
per_page=100


printenv | grep -v "no_proxy" >> /etc/environment

cd $DJANGODIR
# awslogs installation

echo -e "log_group_name = /ecs/ma-$ENVIRONMENT" >> awslogs.conf
echo "Setting up awslogs"
echo -e "Amazon Linux AMI\n$(cat /etc/issue)" > /etc/issue
curl https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cloudwatch/downloads/latest/awslogs-agent-setup.py -O
curl https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cloudwatch/downloads/latest/AgentDependencies.tar.gz -O
tar xvf AgentDependencies.tar.gz -C /tmp/
python ./awslogs-agent-setup.py --region us-east-1 --dependency-path /tmp/AgentDependencies -c awslogs.conf -n

echo "Setting up virtual environment"
source /virtualenvs/platform_analytics/bin/activate
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput

echo "starting gitlab-runner installation"
yum install wget -y
yum install jq -y

echo "starting wget installation"
wget -O /usr/local/bin/gitlab-runner https://gitlab-runner-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/latest/binaries/gitlab-runner-linux-amd64
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/gitlab-runner

echo "unregister all active runners"
gitlab-runner unregister --all-runners

# below line of code will remove any previous zombie runners registered by dead containers
offline_runners=$(curl -s --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:${gitlab_runner_api_access_token}" "${GitlabRunnerUrl}api/v4/runners?tag_list=${tag_filter}&page=${page}&per_page=${per_page}" | jq -r '.[] | .id')
# Iterate over each offline runner and remove it
for runner_id in $offline_runners; do
  echo "Removing runner ID: ${runner_id}"
  curl -s --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN:${gitlab_runner_api_access_token}" --request DELETE "${GitlabRunnerUrl}api/v4/runners/${runner_id}"
done
chown -R gitlab-runner:gitlab-runner /etc
useradd --comment 'GitLab Runner' --create-home gitlab-runner --shell /bin/bash
usermod -aG root gitlab-runner
mkdir /opt/gitlab
/usr/local/bin/gitlab-runner install --user gitlab-runner --working-directory=/opt/gitlab
/usr/local/bin/gitlab-runner start
/usr/local/bin/gitlab-runner register \
                --non-interactive \
                --url ${GitlabRunnerUrl} \
                --registration-token ${GitlabRunnerTokenForService} \
                --executor shell \
                --name ${GitlabRunnerName} \
                --docker-pull-policy always \
                --locked=false \
                --run-untagged=false \
                --docker-privileged=true \
                --limit 1 \
                --tag-list ${GitlabRunnerName}
/usr/local/bin/gitlab-runner restart
chown gitlab-runner /opt/gitlab
chmod -R 777 /opt/gitlab
chmod -R 777 /app/


echo "Starting supervisord"
# this is running as background process
supervisord &

echo "Starting nginx as foreground"
nginx
#
echo "Forever nginx"
```

i want to run commands like supervisorctl on my gitlab-runner but i get permission denied. I tried installing supervisor using gitlab-runner user but it says i need to be root to install software.
I m not able to find a workaround to run supervisorctl as i cannot be root during deployment..
Plzzz help

Comment: Can you run this as two separate ECS tasks, without using supervisord at all?  That would give you the ability to redeploy individual containers when you need to without affecting the others.